# Is it possible to add include path to visual studio from an FTP address?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-studio-2012, ftp

We have a bunch of libraries and projects like OpenCV, Boost and etc. and for that we have a sharing space in our local network. Everyone can access this libraries using ftp protocol and probably by a username and password. I want to know if I can set visual studio additional include or library path from ftp address?
For example for adding include file of opencv you have to add $(OPENCV_DIR)\include which $(OPENCV_DIR) address from your hard drive(c:\opencv\build). I want to address it from ftp such as (ftp://ipaddres/opencv/build). I want to know if it possible or not? and if you can give me another options for my purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you mount that FTP server as a drive and just use that mounted drive as dependency directory in your visual studio?

https://serverfault.com/questions/6079/how-can-i-mount-an-ftp-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows

suggests tools like WebDrive, ExpanDrive, FTPDrive, etc

But take care, visual studio isn't always happy with network folders, afair. But maybe libraries and header are fine there.